# Insert all into select sequence.nextval, sequence not allowed?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to copy data from a table to 3 tables.

I need to input sequence values to 1 or more tables.
But I got an error,  "sequence number not allowed here"

Here is my sql.

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO COM_BOARD(BOD_UID, MNU_UID, BOD_NOTICE, BOD_SUBJECT, BOD_READCNT, BOD_COMMENTCNT, BOD_REF, BOD_LEVEL, BOD_ORDER, BOD_REPLYCNT, BOD_PARENTUID,
    BOD_TAG, BOD_OPEN, BOD_STATE, BOD_DELETE)
 VALUES(BOD_UID, MNU_UID, 0, BOD_SUBJECT, 0, 0, BOD_UID, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0)
INTO COM_BODCONTENT(CON_UID, BOD_UID, MEM_UID, CON_PW, CON_NM, CON_IP, CON_TY, CON_REGYMD, CON_MODYMD, CON_CONTENT)
 VALUES(con_uid, bod_uid, 1, 'adm!!@#!11', 'Admin', '127.0.0.1', 0, input_dt, update_dt, bod_subject)
INTO COM_BODDATA(DAT_UID, BOD_UID, DAT_FILETY, DAT_FILEEXT, DAT_FILENM, DAT_ORGFILENM, DAT_FILESIZE, DAT_DOWNCNT, DAT_STATE)
 VALUES(DAT_UID, BOD_UID, 0, FILE_EXT, IMG, IMG, IMG_SIZE, 0, 1)
SELECT SEQ_BODUID.NEXTVAL BOD_UID, SEQ_CONUID.NEXTVAL CON_UID, SEQ_CONDAT_UID.NEXTVAL DAT_UID, 3141 MNU_UID
  , DECODE(STATE, 'A', 9, 1) BOD_STATE, DECODE(STATE, 'A', 9, 1) BOD_DELETE, SUBJECT/*_kr .. */ bod_subject
  , IMG, IMG_SIZE, SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(IMG, '\.\w+'), 2) FILE_EXT, INPUT_DT, INPUT_WRITER, UPDATE_DT, UPDATE_WRITER, CNT 
from system.t_near_photo
```

Cannot use `insert all into ~ into ~ select sequence.nextval ~~`
or I used wrongly?

Appriciate your any help.

Comment: 'You cannot specify a sequence in any part of a multitable insert statement' - see the last bullet [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9014.htm#i2080134). I think it will actually let you use it in a `values` clause, but it will only be incremented once, so all records would get the same IDs. You probably need to do separate inserts to the three tables.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks to helpful advice. I chose seperate inserts. Thanks so much.